# not able to pass array from one class to another iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

I have a silly doubt, but I need to understand it properly. I have referred few posts on this but they are still confusing to me.

I have an array which consists of set of urls which i got from parsing a xml and I store the array like this:

Parser.m

```
else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"image"]){
    self.img.imageUrl = self.currentElement;
     [[self URL_array]addObject:img.imageUrl]; 

}
```

and if I log the contents it gives the contents as follows:

```
the URL ARRAY IS --------------------->>>>(
"http://www.bedfordevents.co.uk/images/stories/template/GallerySlideshow/b10.jpg\n",
"http://www.bedfordevents.co.uk/images/stories/template/GallerySlideshow/b11.jpg\n",
"http://www.bedfordevents.co.uk/images/stories/template/GallerySlideshow/b12.jpg\n",
"http://www.bedfordevents.co.uk/images/stories/template/GallerySlideshow/b13.jpg\n",
```

I need to pass this array to another class/View controller,for which I've been doing like this in Parser.m file

```
ViewController *control = [[ViewController alloc]init];
control.image_array = URL_array;
```

View controller has an array `image_array`

and I call the array in ViewController.m like this

```
NSLog(@"array is----->>%@ ",self.image_array);
```

But the `image_array` returns null;

I believe I'm doing it wrong somewhere, Can anyone point out my mistake and help me out?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

code updated.
 now I have a method in ViewController as said

```
-(void)updateImageArray:(NSMutableArray *)imageArray{
self.image_array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:imageArray];
NSLog(@"array is in here-------->>>>%@",self.image_array);
}
```

and called

```
[control updateImageArray:URL_array];
```

in my Parser.m and the array is displayed in log in ViewController.m and its working

Thank you

Comment: control.image_array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:URL_array];

Comment: That won't make a difference.

Comment: make a breakpoint at line `control.image_array = URL_array;`to see if you are assigning a proper array. It may occur that at the moment of creation of `control` the parser is not done yet, thus the array is still nil. Also, please show us, how did you declare `image_array` property

Comment: Could we see the definition of `image_array`?

Comment: is "`image_array`" in your "`ViewController`" (terrible name, b.t.w.) a declared "`@property`"?  Are you using ARC, b.t.w.?

Comment: @MichałZygar `@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *image_array;` @michael dautermann: yes i have declared property in viewController

Comment: @MichałZygar i made a break point and logged it and the array contents are being added into image_array. But in `ViewController.m`, I call like this in `viewDidLoad(){ [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"array is----->>%@",self.image_array);}`, but the log shows `array is------>>(null)`

Comment: So it seems like, the viewDidLoad is called BEFORE you set `image_array`. You could add the method `[control updateImageArray:URL_array]` and then inside this method set `self.image_array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:URL_array];` and refresh UI as desired

Comment: @MichałZygar please write your comment in answer section, so that I can accept/vote it as answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you wrote in comments, it seems that the `viewDidLoad` is called BEFORE you set image_array.

You could add the method `[control updateImageArray:URL_array]` and then inside this method set `self.image_array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:URL_array];` and refresh UI as desired

Answer (score 0):

Thats depends on what mode of the `control.image_array` property. So, if it's assign the refcount of the array is not incremented and may be deallocated if source context(Parser.m) releases him. So in ViewController's interface it should be

```
@property(retain, nonatomic)NSArray* image_array
```

or if you use ARC:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic)NSArray* image_array
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description i think you are creating an object of ViewController in parser.m, and you try to `log NSLog(@"array is----->>%@ ",self.image_array)` using another object of ViewController for which value of image array is nil.(try to log self ,controller both will be different).

If you `log NSLog(@"array is----->>%@ ", control.image_array)` from parser.m it will work.

If you need to log it on ViewController.m you may either use delegate methods or pass object of ViewController (ie control) from parser.m to ViewController.m for this you can use external variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override getter method of image_array in ViewController.
This will be good by memory prospective.

In ViewControler.m

```
@synthesize image_array = _image_array;

-(NSMutableArray *)image_array {  
    if(_image_array == nil) {
       _image_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];
      } 
  return _image_array;
}
```

and then do this

```
[control setImage_array:URL_array];
```

Although You can simply do  `[control setImage_array:URL_array];`